# Laravel validation errors not an object in view

Tags: php, arrays, validation, object, laravel

I'm having a strange problem with Laravel.

I'm doing some form validation and in the view `$errors` is an array instead of object thus giving me a PHP error when I do `$errors->has()`

Here is my controller code

```
$v = Validator::make($new_comment, $rules);

    if ($v->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::to_route('named_route', [ $event->slug])->with_errors($v)->with_input();
    }
```

In the controller `$v` is an object but somehow in my views it is an array with the following

```
array(2) { ["messages"]=> array(1) { ["comment"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(43) "The comment must be at least 10 characters." } } ["format"]=> string(8) ":message" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue.

It is the MongoDB session driver I'm using for laravel.

It stores it as an array instead of as an validator object.

I will have to use a different session driver or extend the MongoDB session driver so it acts correctly.